# How could I convert a value that looks like a double into an unsigned long, but properly?

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, double, unsigned

**I am programming in C#** and what I am trying to do is convert this `string` containing a value that seems to be a `double`, so what I did first was convert the `string` into a `double`, then I typecast the `double` into an `unsigned long`. Only problem is that the `unsigned long` is always either a few digits greater or a few digits lower that the value I am suppose to be receiving. But after I typecast the `double` into an `unsigned long`, I convert it into a hexadecimal `string` and pad it.

#### Here is an example of what I am doing:

```cs
string ValueToParse = "2.53327490880368E+15";
double nValue1 = double.Parse(ValueToParse);
ulong nValue2 = (ulong)nValue1;
string str = nValue2.ToString("X16");
```

#### Here are the results of this:

```cs
string str = "00090000070EC260";
```

**This is the problem:**

Right now this seems as if nothing is wrong to the average programmer.
But **what I'm trying to do** is get it so that the value being returned is the **real** result that I am looking for which is **`00090000070EC258`** - **NOT** - **`00090000070EC260`** and I have no clue to what may be causing this difference in values.
The only assumption I can think of that may be causing this value difference is something to do with typecasting the `double` to an `unsigned long` and within the process of the value being converted, something with the precision of the `double` is messing things up.

So please if anybody may know what's going wrong or has any ideas about what may be going wrong, please do respond. I appreciate any help that can be provided. Thanks. :)

Comment: Isn't 2.53327490880368E+15 = 2533274908803680 = 0x00090000070EC260 ? I think it's giving the right answer. I guess I'm an average programmer.

Answer (score 3):

If I plug 90000070EC260 into a programmer's calculator and convert it to decimal, I get a result of 2533274908803680, which corresponds to your original parsed value.

However, if I plug 90000070EC258 in and convert to decimal, I get 2533274908803672, which does *not* correspond to your original parsed value.

Comment: Yes, but 90000070EC258 is what I should be getting.

Comment: @Jake - why do you think you should be getting 90000070EC258, since as Robert has shown, it equals 2533274908803672, not your original 2533274908803680 ?